# bootstrap validator not voting when using solana-genesis or not detected as bootstrap validator

Tags: cluster, local-cluster, development, bootstrap

I am starting a new development cluster and have a new solana-genesis config but am failing to get the bootstrap validator to vote. Using this script, the genesis.bin file is created. My bootstrap validator reports these errors in the logs

> `INFO  solana_core::replay_stage] Haven't landed a vote, so skipping my leader slot`

> `ERROR solana_core::replay_stage] <identity pubkey> No next leader found`

The validator is behind nat and firewall dstnat rules are all added for the used ranges.
Solana gossip reports the validator ports correctly.

**solana-genesis config script:**

```
exec solana-genesis \
        --enable-warmup-epochs \
        --bootstrap-stake-authorized-pubkey bootstrap-validator-keypair.json \
        --bootstrap-validator bootstrap-validator-keypair.json bootstrap-vote-keypair.json bootstrap-stake-keypair.json \
        --bootstrap-validator-lamports 500000000000 \
        --bootstrap-validator-stake-lamports 500000000000 \
        --faucet-lamports 1000000000000000 \
        --faucet-pubkey faucet-keypair.json \
        --fee-burn-percentage 50 \
        --hashes-per-tick auto \
        --ledger /home/sol/genesis-ledger/ \
        --cluster-type development \
```

**bootstrap-validaor start script**

```
exec solana-validator \
        --public-rpc-address <public IP>:12001 \
        --rpc-port 12001 \
        --dynamic-port-range 12003-14019 \
        --gossip-host <public IP> \
        --gossip-port 12000 \
        --rpc-faucet-address <public IP>:14000 \
        --log ~/genesis-ledger/validator.log \
        --identity ~/bootstrap-validator-keypair.json \
        --vote-account ~/bootstrap-vote-keypair.json \
        --ledger ~/genesis-ledger/ \
        --no-os-network-limits-test \
        --no-poh-speed-test \
        --full-rpc-api \
        --rpc-bind-address 10.252.3.40 \
        --bind-address 10.252.3.40 \
```

Answer (score 1):

Believe you want `--no-wait-for-vote-to-start-leader`.

If you're interested in a working configuration, the script in `net/net.sh` starts a local cluster from genesis. it shells out to `net/remote/remote-node.sh` which has a `bootstrap-validator)` section with some config. finally it calls `multinode-demo/bootstrap-validator.sh` with some more config.

Comment: the flag `--no-wait-for-vote-to-start-leader` does allow voting to start, but even though slots are moving, I can not get any transactions to finalize...I can get wallet balances and such from the rpc, but a transfer or airdrop will not ever finalize the transaction...

Comment: see any ERROR or WARN in the logs for the bootstrap? is it actually voting / producing blocks?

Comment: I'd try to use the `net/remote/remote-node.sh` script first and see if there's any major differences between your configuration and a working one.

Comment: I have gone through `/net/remote/remote-node.sh` and `multinode-demo/bootstrap-validator.sh` many times trying to get it to vote. I can call `solana balance` and it shows the balances of my bootstrap keypairs... even `solana airdrop` will register to my faucet and get a signature, but it never finalizes.

Comment: I did just find a WARN log `WARN  solana_rpc::rpc] Bank with Finalized not found at slot: 0`